# How to display javascript content with php exec() function

Tags: javascript, php, phantomjs

I'm writing some php code. I want to display javascript (include phantomjs) variable with php `exec()` function, but it seems like it only opens the file instead of running it. How should I do with this `exec()` function to display javascript variable on the browser.

***php***

```
$response = exec('D:\xampp\htdocs\test.js');
echo $response;
```

Comment: Use <script> tag to include js code

Comment: What's wrong with using a `<script>` tag? If you don't want to load another file in the browser, why not use `file_get_contents`?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
<?php echo get_file_content('D:\xampp\htdocs\test.js'); ?>

// you can call the script functions here. 

<script>
```

this will load the javascript and in the browser it will be executed.

However if can short this pipe-line more by directly loading the script text into a variable and calling eval function.

```
<script>
var code = "alert('test');";
eval(code);
</script>
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Include your JavaScript like this in your PHP:

```
<script src="<?php echo 'test.js'; ?>"></script>
```

It should render into:

```
<script src="test.js"></script>
```

Note that you don't need to link to `D:\xampp\htdocs\`, because Apache should make this file accessible at `localhost:80/test.js' (80 is the default port it use).

Which you could simply call without using PHP in your case.

You would want to use PHP if you have some function that declares the base URL. This way the link declarations aren't static. Which means you can move all your files to another server without having to change all the URLs.

For example:

```
<script src="<?php echo getBaseURL() . '/test.js'; ?>"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="<?php echo getBaseURL(); ?>/test.js"></script>
```

Both options do the same, it's up to your own preference how you like to concatenate the strings.

Note that `getBaseURL()` isn't a native PHP function, so you have to make it yourself. There should be plenty of useful code snippets on the web.

Answer (score -1):

Php file can execute only runnable interfaces do not run client side script. It just open js files .

Or Use like this

```
<?php 
$response = exec('D:\xampp\htdocs\test.js');
?>

<script>
<?php echo $response; ?>
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you think that `exec` returns something? Is that an executable to be run?

Comment: What you are giving inside the file it can be able to print.  but javascript can not  run without <script> tag.

Comment: ...but why should one use `exec`? That will run and execute an executable file. It will not grab the content of that JS file to include it, that's what `file_get_contents` should be used for

Comment: Not necessary you can use anything to display js files. Include, file_get_contents or exec I just answered for the above question. I am  suggesting here not necessary to use "exec" function for js files .